# Pseudo panel data

Tags: r, panel-data, dataset, cross-section

I have data that looks like this

```
ID  iter number type  date
18A15   1   1   RS  01/01/2016  22:21:53 
18A15   2   2   RS  01/01/2016  22:31:06
18A15   3   2   RS  01/01/2016  22:51:47
18A15   4   1   RS  01/01/2016  22:59:53
18A15   5   2   RS  01/01/2016  23:00:32
18A15   6   1   RS  01/01/2016  23:15:12
18A15   7   1   RZ  01/01/2016  23:25:32
18A15   8   2   RZ  01/01/2016  23:45:25 
18A15   9   2   RT  01/01/2016  23:53:45 
18A15   10  1   RE  01/01/2016  00:14:36   
18A16   1   2   ZE  02/01/2016  09:05:45    
18A16   2   1   ZA  02/01/2016  09:10:55
18A16   3   1   RD  02/01/2016  09:26:32
18A16   4   1   RC  02/01/2016  09:35:42
18A16   5   2   AS  02/01/2016  09:45:36
```

The first column are ids, I want to study each id as a whole because all the caracteristics that we have in each column make our final product.

So I would like to know if this data is a pseudo panel data ? 
And what would be the best method for a data analysis?

Comment: This is a panel. But could you please elaborate on "*I want to study each id as a whole*". What does that mean? – *Reviewer*

Comment: I want to establish a comparison " Inter " type which means inter ID each ID represents a type of product